# Waiting a second between each returned response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a web app that connects to an external API.

That API has a limit of 3 connections per second.

I have a method that gets employee data for a whole factory.

It works fine, but I've found that if a particular factory has a lot of employees, I hit the API connection limit and get an error.

`(429) API calls exceeded...maximum 3 per Second`

So I decided to use `await Task.Delay(1000)` to set a 1 second delay, every time this method is used.

Now it seems to have reduced the number of errors I get, but I am still getting a few limit errors.

Is there another method I could use to ensure my limit is not reached?

Here is my code:

```
public async Task<YourSessionResponder> GetAll(Guid factoryId)
    {
        UserSession.AuthData sessionManager = new UserSession.AuthData
        {
            UserName = "xxxx",
            Password = "xxxx"
        };


        ISessionHandler sessionMgr = new APIclient();

        YourSessionResponder response;

        response = await sessionMgr.GetDataAsync(sessionManager, new ListerRequest
        {
            FactoryId = factoryId;

        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return response;
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
var yourEmployees = GetAll(factoryId);
```

Comment: If the limit is 3 connections per second and you're waiting 1 second between each connection then it seems that there may be a different limit you're reaching or error you're getting.  Have you confirmed that it's the exact same error?  Are there differences between what you're showing us and your actual code?

Comment: Two questions (1) How are you calling `GetAll`? Does that code await the results? (2) Have you externally confirmed (e.g. with Fiddler or Wireshark) that your requests aren't going out more often than once per second?

Comment: @JohnWu Thank you , Hi, I have never used Fiddler or Wireshark.   I am calling it like this: `var yourEmployees = GetAll(factoryId);`

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use a cheap/free version of an API that you probably should be paying for to remove that limitation - doubly so if this is something you're deploying in a **factory**.  API limits like that are to stop you from doing what it seems like you're trying to do...

Comment: Maybe try `var yourEmployees = await GetAll(factoryId);` You need to await it, or else `GetAll` could run in parallel with itself.

Comment: @David yes, I added the error code to my question. The code is the same, I just copied it here.  thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: *"The code is the same, I just copied it here."* - That doesn't seem likely, since the code in the question contains syntax errors.  The operation starting with `response = await sessionMgr.GetDataAsync` is incomplete.  The error you'd see when trying to compile this code wouldn't be coming from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment on the question:

> I am calling it like this: `var yourEmployees = GetAll(factoryId);`

Then you're not awaiting the task.  While there's a 1-second delay after each network operation, you're still firing off all of the network operations in rapid succession.  You need to await the task before moving on to the next one:

```
var yourEmployees = await GetAll(factoryId);
```

Assuming that this is happening in some kind of loop or repeated operation, of course.  Otherwise, where would all of these different network tasks be coming from?  Whatever high-level logic is invoking the multiple network operations, that logic needs to await one before moving on to the next.

Comment: What if 3 requests call ``await GetAll(factoryId)`` on exact same time?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad: That depends on whether this operation is invoked directly by client requests or whether it's controlled in server-side logic that's responding to only one client request.  I suppose the former is possible, though I was under the impression that the question was indicating the latter.  If users can directly invoke this operation then it would need to be abstracted even more, perhaps placed into a queue and processed separately from the web app.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a web app that connects to an external API.

Your current code limits the number of outgoing requests made by a *single* incoming request to your API. What you need to do is limit *all* of your outgoing requests, app-wide.

It's *possible* to do this using a `SemaphoreSlim`:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim Mutex = new(1);
public async Task<YourSessionResponder> GetAll(Guid factoryId)
{
  ...
  YourSessionResponder response;

  await Mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    response = await sessionMgr.GetDataAsync(...);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }
  finally
  {
    Mutex.Release();
  }

  return response;
}
```

But I would take a different approach...

> Is there another method I could use to ensure my limit is not reached?

Generally, I recommend just retrying on 429 errors, using de-correlated jittered exponential backoff (see [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#available-via-polly-contrib) for an easy implementation). That way, when you're "under budget" for the time period, your requests go through immediately, and they only slow down when you hit your API limit.

Comment: Oh I see, so if the the response is 429, then wait a second?   Thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: Sort of. The Polly approach delays and retries only after a 429, but the logic around when to retry is much more complex than just waiting a second.